# Numeric values from a String

Tags: java, calculator, physics

I am creating a physics calculator and currently working on average velocity. For displacement I would like the user to input a string i.e. "5km north". Then using a method assign only the numeric values in the string to be doubles using Double.parseDouble or something of the like.

Below is my method to pull out numeric values

```
        private double getNumericalValue(String userInput) {
        double numericalOutput = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
            if (userInput.charAt(i) >= 65 && userInput.charAt(i) <= 122) {
                numericalOutput = Double.parseDouble(userInput.substring(0, i));
            }
        }
        return numericalOutput;
    }
```

and lastly the getAverageVelocity method

```
        private void getAverageVelocity() {
        // formula average velocity = displacement s / change in time t
        double avgVelocity = 0.0;
        System.out.println("Enter the displacement: [ex. 5 km north]");
        String displacement = getStringInput();
        System.out.println("Enter the change in time: [ex. 1 hour]");
        String changeInTime = getStringInput();
        // parse the string and change numerical input into double
        double numericalS = getNumericalValue(displacement);
        double numericalT = getNumericalValue(changeInTime);

        avgVelocity = numericalS / numericalT;

        System.out.println("The Average Velocity is: " + avgVelocity);
    }
```

As you can see I figured I could simply compare chars to their ascii value. However, it is including the k or a space in my double output which is throwing this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5 k"
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:556)
at Main.getNumericalValue(Main.java:122)
at Main.getAverageVelocity(Main.java:393)
at Main.kineticsIn1DCalculator(Main.java:375)
at Main.performAction(Main.java:141)
at Main.runner(Main.java:29)
at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Any help and a thorough explanation would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `For input string: "5 k"` shows you are trying to parse the string `"5 k"`. If that's not what you're expecting to be parsing, work out why it's that string.

Comment: Hint: you're parsing in a loop, and the exception isn't occurring on the first thing you parse.

Comment: Using numeric ASCII values (actually, they're Unicode values) is unreadable. Use `'0'` to `'9'` instead, since `'0'` means the same thing as `48`. The only difference is that the former is a `char` and the latter an `int`, but chars are actually numeric values that can be used in arithmetic expressions and compared with other numeric values.

Comment: it would seem that the logic in my if statement is also incorrect, as I don't want to include the ascii values for the range of (a-z and A-Z), and instead it is including them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are actually testing in the if block is whether the character at *i* is a letter A-Z, a-z and other symbols(i.e. [ ^ ], ...etc) to check if it's a number (i.e. 0-9) the corresponding decimal range is 48-57 [check this link](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:ASCII-Table-wide.svg)

as for the exception it's because of substring(0, 0) will result in an empty string, and when trying to parse it, Double.parseDouble() will throw an exception.
here is a solution you can use:

```
    private double getNumericalValue(String userInput) {
    double numericalOutput = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
        if (userInput.charAt(i) >= 48 && userInput.charAt(i) <= 57) {
            numericalOutput = Double.parseDouble(userInput.substring(0, i + 1));
        }
    }
    return numericalOutput;
}
```

Note: substring(i, j) i is inclusive, j exclusive

**Update :**
just noticed, in your case the exception happens because you are trying to parse the letter "k" since it passes the condition, resulting in Double.parseDouble() throwing an exception.

Comment: Yep thank you for that, Andy Turner also pointed it out in a round about way.

Comment: Though the other posts did give me some different ways to fix the issue, I enjoyed yours best as it stayed true to how I want the method to look. Thanks.

Comment: @Walt you are welcome, just as @k314159 pointed out you can make your code more readable by replacing the ASCII values with the actual characters, the test becomes `userInput.charAt(i) >= '0' && userInput.charAt(i) <= '9'`

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because even if the first number is found the `for` loop continues. You simply have to add `break` instruction, then the for loop ends at the first number found.

This is the final code of the method `getNumericalValue`:

```java
private double getNumericalValue(String userInput) {
    double numericalOutput = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
        if (userInput.charAt(i) >= 65 && userInput.charAt(i) <= 122) {
            numericalOutput = Double.parseDouble(userInput.substring(0, i));
            break;
        }
    }
    return numericalOutput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply should input the line and parse its parts.

Best to introduce a class to hold a value with unit, where "km north" counts as a unit.

Since java 14 there exists the `record` class.

```
record ValueWithUnit(double value, String unit) {
    public static ValueWithUnit from(String s) {
        String v = s.replaceFirst("^(.*?)([ A-z].*)$", "$1");
        String u = s.replaceFirst("^(.*?)([ A-z].*)$", "$2");
        if (u == v) {
            u = "";
        }
        double x = Double.parseDouble(v); // Replaces getNumericalValue(v);
        return new Value(x, u);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String.format("%f %s", value, unit);
    }
}
```

You could use it directly as:

```
ValueWithUnit vu = new ValueWithUnit(30.0, "km");
System.out.println(vu);
```

The code then becomes:

```
private void getAverageVelocity() {
    // formula average velocity = displacement s / change in time t
    double avgVelocity = 0.0;
    System.out.println("Enter the displacement: [ex. 5 km north]");
    ValueWithUnit displacement = ValueWithUnit.from(getStringInput());
    System.out.println("Enter the change in time: [ex. 1 hour]");
    ValueWithUnit changeInTime = ValueWithUnit.from(getStringInput());
    // parse the string and change numerical input into double
    double numericalS = displacement.value;
    double numericalT = changeInTime.value;

    avgVelocity = numericalS / numericalT;

    System.out.printf("The Average Velocity is: %f %s%n", avgVelocity,
        displacement.unit + "/" + changeInTime.unit);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a real cool object/class (forgive me if I am using the wrong terminology as I am an amateur) However, I really want to break it down barney style and try to not use to many extra object/classes that do most of the work for me. In the future I will be sure to use this.